# Cannot run executable in Github actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to create a test for any pull request (PR) for a github repository.

This is my test.yml file (it has a tree and version step because of the error I'm getting):

```
name: Test ACI

on: [pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

run-name: Test ACI

jobs:

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install pandas matplotlib

      - name: Checkout repo
        run: git checkout
        
      - name: Initial tree
        run: pwd && tree .
        
      - name: Samtools version
        run: ls -alh /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools && /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools version
```

This is the output of 'Initial tree':

```
/home/runner/work/ACI/ACI
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── aci
├── assets
│   ├── aci.png
│   └── genome_depth.png
├── bin
│   └── samtools
│       ├── samtools
│       └── samtools.pl
└── test
    ├── amplicon_depth.png
    ├── genome_depth.png
    ├── test.bam
    └── test.bed
```

This is the output of 'Samtools version' (contains the error 'No such file or directory'):

```
Run ls -alh /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools && /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools version
  ls -alh /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools && /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools version
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
-rwxr-xr-x 1 runner docker 784K Jul 20 20:31 /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools
/home/runner/work/_temp/584946ba-f45e-43e0-9d57-8b72fbf251c6.sh: line 1: /home/runner/work/ACI/ACI/bin/samtools/samtools: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

But, isn't this file there? `tree` and `ls -alh` can both find it. I think there is something about executables and github actions that I'm missing.

I have verified that the file is there. I'm just confused why it isn't an executable anymore.

Comment: The `git checkout` step is redundant, `actions/checkout` does that for you. For the path, try using `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` instead of `/home/runner/work/ACI/ACI`.

Comment: Additionally, consider using [setup-python](https://github.com/actions/setup-python).

Comment: Verified it on my side and it indeed is an issue. Checked `samtools` binary with `file` and `ldd`. `ldd` output shows `libhts.so.3 => not found`. These threads (https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system) would be helpful too. Built and installed from source and it worked fine. You might need to recompile it and put all its dependencies along side it too to make it run (or, maybe, build a static binary).

Comment: You may check this test here: workflow (https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5620120562/workflow) and run (https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5620120562/job/15228452098).

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for looking into this! Installing samtools from source in the github action seems to be the only way I get my test to work.

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to take a look at https://github.com/actions/cache to cache it for subsequent workflows runs. That would certainly save some time if that becomes an issue.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I think I'm going to just use pysam instead